# Using skrollr.js and window resizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, resize

I have a website where the main page is composed of a main area and a secondary area with a menu at the top, the main area is resized automatically depending on the width and height of the monitor:

```
W = $(window).width();
H = $(window).height();
```

And then

```
$("#toparea").css('width', W);
$("#toparea").css("height", H);
```

Thing is I'm ussing [skrollr.js](http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/) plugin to pin some elements, and I was wondering how to use those W and H I've already created to pin those elements in the variable position.

For example, if the height of the browser is 860, how should I do it with the skrollr plugin so it detects the height is 860pixels.

```
<div id="menubar" data-1="top:100%" data-H="top:0%;" >
```

So, once you've scrolled H pixels, the menu will pin at the top of the screen.

How can I code that so the skrollr plugin understands what H means?

Perhaps there's some method to do it in the api, but so far no luck here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want:

Sounds like a good use case for using a relative anchor (you should use skrollr > 0.4 if you don't already do):

```
<div id="menubar" data-1="top:100%" data-top-top="top:0%;" >
```

`data-top-top` means "when the top of the element is at the top of the viewport". Since these values are calculated up front, it should work even though your element is in fact positioned absolute and doesn't move.

Here's an official example using skrollr 0.4.2 (required) http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/examples/fixed_nav.html